# Notify Property Changed not working

Tags: c#, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

this my xml code

```XAML
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Tag="{Binding id,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

this is my model

```C#
public string _Name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set { _Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); }
}
```

when i set value to these two propertie ie. to id and Name

but its not notifying to Name ...

Comment: Did you forget to set the this.DataContext? and that is really not a model, it's just a Property :)

Comment: ohh yes !!its property..

Comment: i have set datacontext too,still its not working :(

Comment: k, is this WPF application?

Comment: show how your setting these properties and where you are assigning the DataContext

Answer (score 3):

Simple Databinding Example with Updates.  You can use this as a reference to get you started :)

```C#
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // implement the INotify
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string _mytext;
    public String MyText
    {
        get { return _mytext;  }
        set { _mytext = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyText"); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = this;             // set the datacontext to itself :)
        MyText = "Change Me";
    }
}
```

---

```XAML
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" Foreground="White" Background="Black"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: shocking dont know why this is happening ..previous collection was declare correctoly

Comment: awesome, looking for the bug would probably be a worthwhile venture.  good luck :)